# C#.Net printing one character of a string at a time in a TextBox

Tags: c#

Am new to C# and i need your help on this, I want to display one character at a time in a textbox this is my code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;  //why does this don't increment when it ticks again?
    string str = "Herman Lukindo";
    textBox1.Text += str[i];
    i++; 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(timer1.Enabled == false )
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        button1.Text = "Stop";
    }
    else if(timer1 .Enabled == true )
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        button1.Text = "Start";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting i to zero every time the timer ticks.

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's good for a first time post

Comment: `if(timer1.Enabled) { } else { }`... much nicer (with line breaks that  is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with you code is that you are assigning `i = 0` with every tick, so it will always be `0` everytime it is used. I would suggest using a class level variable for this.

However, using a variable at class level means you are going to need to reset to `0` at some point, probably each time you start the timer.

A further point is that you are going to want to validate the tick event to ensure you don't try to access an index that doesn't exist (`IndexOutOfRangeException`). For this I would recommend automatically stopping the timer once the last letter has been printed.

With all that in mind, here is my suggested code:

```
int i = 0;// Create i at class level to ensure the value is maintain between tick events.
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Herman Lukindo";
    // Check to see if we have reached the end of the string. If so, then stop the timer.
    if(i >= str.Length)
    {
        StopTimer();
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text += str[i];
        i++; 
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If timer is running then stop it.
    if(timer1.Enabled)
    {
        StopTimer();
    }
    // Otherwise (timer not running) start it.
    else
    {
        StartTimer();
    }
}

void StartTimer()
{
    i = 0;// Reset counter to 0 ready for next time.
    textBox1.Text = "";// Reset the text box ready for next time.
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    button1.Text = "Stop";
}

void StopTimer()
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    button1.Text = "Start";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> why does this don't increment when it ticks again?

Because your variable `i` is local to your event. You need to define it at class level.

```
int i = 0;  //at class level
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Herman Lukindo";
    textBox1.Text += str[i];
    i++; 
}
```

On exit of your event, variable `i` becomes out of scope and looses its value. On the next event it is considered a new local variable with the initialized value of `0`.

Next, you should also look for cross threaded exception. Since your `TextBox` is not getting updated on the UI thread.

Comment: Might what some validation thrown in there too... save relying on the user clicking the stop button when the last letter is printed

Comment: thank you so much brother and thanks every body its my first time to ask a question and its has been answered perfectly am so happy its worked

Comment: thank you very much, i have sent you an Email please check it

Comment: @musefan, yes i really need that too can you help me please because am facing the situation now after the last letter is printed out am getting an error message

Comment: @HermanGideon: I will post you another answer. Hold on for a couple of mins

Comment: @musefan, i have tried this and it executed without an error ,        public int i = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            string str = "Herman Lukindo";
            
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text += str[i];
                if (i == str.Length)
                {
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }catch (IndexOutOfRangeException){
                
            }
            i++;
            

        }

Comment: @HermanGideon: For performance reasons it is best not to use `try` blocks to handle your logic flow. See my answer for my recommendations

Comment: @musefan thank you very much i have learnt something from your code it worked perfectly